# how to break lines in Webview using Jsoup if no <br> is used to break text in original page

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to open certain part of this page in a webview using Jsoup,

> http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/12/20/heads_up_if_tor_goes_down_over_the_weekend_this_is_why/

The problem with the page is, the text inside `<pre>` tag is showing in a single line thus causing horizontal scroll bar. Even though I managed to disable Horizontal scrolling in `webview`, but this is not what I want.

I want the text inside `<pre>` tag to be shown how it is originally displaying on the page,

This is the text,

```
IP address       Who owns the block containing this IP?
128.31.0.39      AS3       Massachusetts Institute of Technology
86.59.21.38      AS8437    Tele2 Telecommunication GmbH
194.109.206.212  AS3265    XS4ALL Internet BV
82.94.251.203    AS3265    XS4ALL Internet BV
131.188.40.189   AS680     Verein zur Foerderung eines Deutschen Forschungsnetzes e.V.
193.23.244.244   AS50472   Chaos Computer Club e.V.
208.83.223.34    AS40475   Applied Operations, LLC
171.25.193.9     AS198093  Foreningen for digitala fri- och rattigheter
154.35.32.5      AS14987   Rethem Hosting LLC
199.254.238.52   AS16652   Riseup Networks
```

The above text is displaying in a single line in Webview.

When I see the source code of this part of the page, there is no `<br>` tags used to break lines and I guess this is why it is displaying in a single line in a Webview.

How am I supposed to break it into lines in WebView when there is no `<br>` tag used for line break in original page ?

Comment: i think `\r\n` and `\n` in <pre> tag is taken as linebreaker

Comment: so you are implying that jsoup doesn't handle \r\n ?

Comment: i am not sure what happens at jsoup, but if you try a sample HTML file, with <pre> and \r\n at end of lines, they will be breaked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try \n?
I believe that \n inside  will work.

Comment: try how ? your answer is ambigious